# EntityFramework Query Returns the same object for relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having trouble phrasing the title into something that makes more sense, so I'm going to be a little verbose in my question.

I have this EF query:

```
    var allSocs = _db.Socs
    .Where(x => x.Soc6 != null)
    .Select(x => new SocModel {
        OccupationalEmploymentStatistics = x.OccupationalEmploymentStatistics
                    .Where(y => y.GeographyId == 25 && y.Release == "2015A01" && y.Naics == "000000")
                    .OrderByDescending(z => z.AnnualWageMedian),
        Soc6 = x.Soc6,
        OnetSocs = x.OnetSoc,
        Name = x.Name,
        Description = x.Description,
        EmploymentProjections = x.EmploymentProjections
                    .Where(y => y.GeographyId == "201400" && y.Naics == "000000")
    }).ToList();
```

It's returning a list of Objects called `Soc`s, who have some primitive properties and three Object properties, `Onetsocs`, `OccupationalEmploymentStatistics`, and `EmploymentProjections`.

The behavior I'm having is that all of the non-object fields are working fine, as are `EmploymentProjections` and `OnetSocs`.

The issue is that `OccupationalEmploymentStatistics` is acting weird.  It seems to be that EF is only getting *one* `OccupationalEmploymentStastic` and applying it to all records in `_db.Socs`.

If I set a breakpoint and mouse over `_db.Socs`, I'm shown that there is [only one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcULq.jpg) object.  However, `allSocs` has the proper number of Socs in it (841).

I've tried removing the `OrderByDescending` to see if maybe that was the issue, but I'm still getting the same behavior.

For some background info, the tables that I'm working with are all external tables, and I had to draw the relationships manually since EF didn't pick up on them.

EDIT: Some more background info.  If I make another query that's just 
`var socs = _db.Socs.ToList()`, only the first record has any `OccupationalEmploymentStatistics` at all.  None of the other records have any

Answer (score 0):

Because EF uses the Identity Map pattern. Basically, an EF session will only store one instance for a given entity and id, and it will always reuse the same instance, whenever some entity points to the same DB table and primary key.

Comment: Interesting.. I'm not familiar with that term at all.  How do I get around it to get the data I need?