# EntityFramework External Tables not getting all data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a bunch (~20) external tables that I'm working with for an app.  I'm having a problem with a large query, that I think I've traced down partially, but I'm stuck on the actual solution.  [Here](http://prntscr.com/e918jt) is a screenshot of my edmx, showing the two tables and the relationship.

Whenever I select `Socs` from  the database (via `_db.Socs.ToList()`), I'm expecting each `Soc` to have a List of `OccupationalEmploymentStatistics`.  However, the behavior I'm seeing is that only the **First** `Soc` has any `OccupationalEmploymentStatistics` (at least by debugging and manually looking through about 20 of the 841 records returned.  All 841 records should have `OccupationalEmploymentStatistics`, although it's a nullable field).

When I tried to filter down into *just* Socs with `oes`, via this: `var allSocs = _db.Socs.Where(x => x.OccupationalEmploymentStatistics != null).ToList();`, I get

```
Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[MCCDIP.SPA.Data.OccupationalEmploymentStatistic, MCCDIP.SPA.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.
```

I'm totally at a loss for what's going on here.

Comment: the where clause you have is trying to compare an object to != null. The where clause can only be used against thiings like int and string hence the primitive types error if you want o compare an object use Any instead of Where

Comment: Right... Just figured that out.  Okay, that's taken care of, and I do seem to be getting them now as long as I enumerate the OccupationalEmploymentStatistics.  I'm still having this issue though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249043/entityframework-query-returns-the-same-object-for-relationship

Comment: You did not mention if you use lazy loading or not, and because of the lack of a code snippet I also do not know if your DbContext (_db) has been disposed or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all Socs that doesn't have any OccupationalEmploymentStatistic, you can use the following linq query:

```
var query = 
   from s in _db.Socs
   join oes in _db.OccupationalEmploymentStatistics on oes.Soc equals s.Soc1 into gj
   from oes in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
   where oes == null
   select s;

query = query.Distinct();
```

If you want all Socs with the collection OccupationalEmploymentStatistics loaded you can use the following query:

```
var query = 
   from s in _db.Socs
       .Include(x => x.OccupationalEmploymentStatistics)
   select s;
```